# Elasticsearch mapping : how to store a not-indexed field that could be of different types

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I am trying to store a document 'doc' in which one of the field 'doc.value' can be of different type (float, string, object...). I know I can't have it indexed that way, but I just want it to be stored (no search on doc.value, the search will be based on other 'doc' fields).

My first idea was to use the 'index/_type' to deal with it, but it appears to be against good practices and even impossible with ES 2.0 (stated [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/11812)).

I could use a 'dynamic:false' setting on 'doc' level and skip the 'value' field in my mapping declaration; but I need the dynamic behaviour for the other fields in 'doc'.

I could move the 'doc.value' field into a 'doc.inner.value' and set 'doc.inner' mapping as an object with 'dynamic:false'; but in that case; I would have to modify each document when I store them and retrieve them.

The last solution I see would be to create my own 'type' (like 'any_type') via a plugin and I would map 'doc.value' to this 'any_type'. But this solution is obviously not the road I would like to take...

So I was wondering what was the good solution for this problem, if there was any.

Answer (score 0):

The first proposition would be the best in most of the cases, but as you need dynamic mapping for your others fields, the second solution is the easiest (creating a sub-field with dynamic mapping disabled while keeping it enabled at in root object).

1) Create the `inner` object field with `dynamic:"false"` setting :

```
POST dynamic
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "inner": {
          "type": "object",
          "dynamic": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2)Add some values to test (with fields like `new_string` and `new_long` to be dynamically created too):

```
    PUT dynamic/test/1
    {
      "new_string":"lorem ipsum",
      "inner":{
        "sub_object":{
          "field1": "value1",
          "field2": 123
        }
      }
    }

    PUT dynamic/test/2
    {
      "new_long":1234,
      "inner":{
        "field3": "value2",
        "field4": 123
      }
    }
```

3)As the source of your document is stored by default, and it is exactly the JSON document you provided to ElasticSearch, you will have your inner values in the response, even if not indexed or stored :

```
"hits": [
             {
                "_index": "dynamic",
                "_type": "test",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                   "new_string": "lorem ipsum",
                   "inner": {
                      "sub_object": {
                         "field1": "value1",
                         "field2": 123
                      }
                   }
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "dynamic",
                "_type": "test",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                   "new_long": 1234,
                   "inner": {
                      "field3": "value2",
                      "field4": 123
                   }
                }
             }
          ]
```

4)Check the mapping to see that the `new_string` and `new_long` fields mapping has been created :

```
"dynamic": {
      "mappings": {
         "test": {
            "properties": {
               "inner": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "dynamic": "false"
               },
               "new_long": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "new_string": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this feedback. You made this solution very clear now. The drawback to transform the original document is strong for me (I would like to retrieve 'as is' the original document). But as you said it may be the best solution if no 'perfect one' exists for me.

Comment: You're welcome. Just a last thing : beware if you have very large number of dynamic fields as the mapping will grow accordingly.